# "Before it was too late" vs. "before it would be too late"

Tags: meaning, differences, verbs, aspect

What is the difference between the sentences below?

> 1. Mary decided to get pregnant before it was too late.
> 2. Mary decided to get pregnant before it would be too late.

Comment: I think that under a grammatical perspective there is no difference because either are ungrammatical.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider You would be incorrect about that.

Comment: @snail, I was taught by my teacher that in (1) you should use 'were' and in (2) 'it would have been', so what are you talking about?

Comment: Both sound good to me. There might possibly be slight differences in some contexts, maybe. Anyway . . .

Comment: In both cases Mary avoided extinction! Hallelujah!

Answer (score 2):

Regarding 1)

- This is colloquial, i.e. what native speakers would say. Use this one.
- The commenter's suggestion "before it *were* too late" isn't necessary.

Regarding 2)

- I can't imagine a scenario where that sentence would be appropriate. Adding 'would' turns the sentence into a conditional, but the first half ("Mary decided to get pregnant") is awkward next to this conditional, and has no 'if' (or equatable) statement. If there is to be a conditional in this part of the story, split it into a new sentence.
- The commenter's suggestion for "it would have been" is correct, given the sentence is written in the past tense.

Answer (score 1):

The way I hear most people say it is " before it's/it is too late."  I must admit that I don't often hear people say the two you have down there.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to EL&U. Cool name, by the way.